# Docker Desktop - VM doesn't start due to "[FAIL] DD0017: can a VM be started? vm has not started"

Tags: docker, kvm-virtualization, 23.10

I have a problem with Docker Desktop - it stopped working when I tried to move `Docker.raw` file location with Docker Desktop GUI.

The processes of Docker Desktop start, but there's no UI, Docker commands don't work when  `docker-desktop` context is used. I suppose the issue is related to the VM used by Docker Desktop since the diagnostic tool `com.docker.diagnose check` gives me the following error:

```
[FAIL] DD0017: can a VM be started? vm has not started: failed to open kmsg.log: open /home/lukasz/.docker/desktop/log/vm/kmsg.log: no such file or directory
```

Creating `kmsg.log` doesn't help.

I found this [GitHub issue in desktop-linux repo](https://github.com/docker/desktop-linux/issues/173), I posted my problem in the thread, but I doubt anyone will address the issue as no one has relplied to the issue creator since October.

Docker commands work if I switch the context to a default one.

What I tried so far:

- purging Docker and Docker Desktop (and all Docker related folders) multiple times
- added my user to docker user group
- checked if virtualization wasn't disabled in BIOS
- installed older versions of docker desktop
- checked KVM virtualization support

Any guidance would is appreciated.